# Oracle Agile PLM-Customisation

Tags: java, agile, oracle-agile-plm

In my company, we are using Oracle Agile PLM 9.3.5. So far we never did any customisation. Now we want to customise the standard product. I am new to this product. Does anybody have any idea how to proceed with customisation?

Requirement:
In the ECO, there is a tab called "Affected Items". We want to add a button to print out the changed items as part of that ECO.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using External URL PX, tied to Action Menu event. This will create a menu item in the Action menu of the ECO. Upon clicking the link, it will open the web page in a different window where you can use Agile SDK to display what needs to be printed out.